# Cannot login to SQL Server instance installed on Debian using domain account

Tags: active-directory, debian, sql-server, debian-buster, integrated-authentication

I can login to SQL Server 2019 (installed on Debian Buster) with SA account using SQL Management Studio on Windows Server 2016, but I cannot do this with the domain account using integrated authentication.

1.
The DebianVM (hyper-v) has joined to Active Directory and the domain account can login through SSH to that server.

2.
I have successfully installed SQL Server 2019 and created the instance on the DebianVM.

3.
I have successfully logged in to that instance with the SA account using SQL Management Studio (latest version).

4.
I have successfully added the domain account to that instance (using SQL Management studio) with sysadmin role.

**5.
I cannot log in to the instance using the domain account (that I added with SQL Management Studio) and integrated authentication with SQL Management Studio.**

*ERROR IN SQL MANAGEMENT STUDIO:*

```
Cannot connect to 172.xxx.xxx.xxx.
Additional information:
Login failed. The login is from an untrasted domain 
and cannot be used with Integrated Authentication.
(Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18452)
```

Any ideas what could be the reason or where should I look?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps to configure Active Directory authentication on SQL Server (Linux). [Here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15) you will find a full tuorial.

The following list provides a summary with a link to each section in the tutorial:

1. [Join a SQL Server host to an Active Directory domain](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-active-directory-join-domain?view=sql-server-ver15).
2. [Create an AD user for SQL Server and set the ServicePrincipalName](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15#createuser).
3. [Configure the SQL Server service keytab](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15#configurekeytab).
4. [Secure the keytab file](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15#configurekeytab).
5. [Configure SQL Server to use the keytab file for Kerberos authentication](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15#configurekeytab).
6. [Create AD-based SQL Server logins in Transact-SQL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15#createsqllogins).
7. [Connect to SQL Server using AD authentication](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15#connect).